# Remove HTML tags but implement line breaks from text (Regex and Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, regex, text, tags

I have a paragraph of text coming from the backend that has 
 within curly brackets like so:

```
...some text { <br /> } { <br /> } ...more text
```

and some inline HTML styling like:

```
...some text <strong>some text</strong>
```

I need to remove all of these but need break where the line breaks are.

How can these be done with Regex?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that doesn't require regex. However, since I don't know the content of your html, it might **NOT** work well. So, test it to make sure.

The first part is a simple text replace, so it doesn't require regex

```
htmlData.replaceAll('{ <br /> } ', '\n');
```

Then, you create a DOM element, insert all the html data into it, and get the `innerText` attribute that is the text data without the tags.

```js
const p = '...some text <strong>some text</strong> more text <b>more</b> text...some text { <br /> } { <br /> } ...more text';
console.log("BEFORE: "+p);

let tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
// Replace into newlines.
tmp.innerHTML = p.replaceAll('{ <br /> } ', '\n');
// Get the text.
console.log("AFTER: "+tmp.innerText);
```

Comment: Ok great. Since I'm working in React, accessing the DOM would involve a getRef? And React Native?

Comment: You didn't mention anything about React, I assumed this was purely a front-end issue. I'm not sure this method would be that easy to implement in React.